# Wording of this Microsoft error message

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I have a C# multithreaded application and I ran into a simple problem when two different threads collided calling a routine that writes out a data file.  The program had been converted over from an ancient VB program so the file code in this routine was all using VBNET.FileSystem calls, i.e.,

```
VBNET.FileSystem.FreeFile()
```

...

```
VBNET.FileSystem.FileOpen(...)
```

...

```
VBNET.FileSystem.WriteLine(...)
```

...

```
VBNET.FileSystem.FileClose(...)
```

The exception said (with proprietary stuff obfuscated...)

> "The process cannot access the file 'C:\xxxx\yyyy\zzz.txt' because it
>   is being used by another process"

It was easy enough to fix by making it thread-safe, but it was the **wording** of the exception I was curious about.  Why **process**?   The problem was a threading issue, not a process one, and making the routine a critical section fixed the problem.   Do VBNET file I-O operations spawn separate processes?

Comment: if it was a fully separate process, you'd see it in task manager...

Comment: @paqogomez The terminology is not the same.  Every process has at least one thread, but not every thread is a process.  A process can contain many threads.

Comment: I think that error message dates back to before threads even existed.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the way you solved the problem: did you add the necessary to make it thread safe with the app threads solely? Or was it a more "drastic" approach? Isn't possible to make an app thread safe but not concurrent process-safe? What if the devices used to arbiter concurrent accesses are only known by your process? Then your app would still be sensitive to another process accesses?

Comment: Just that app.  It's the only app that uses that file and the app is a singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely says "process" because for the error message to say "thread" would be equally misleading as it would imply a different thread within your process, when in fact it could be a totally different process.  All the low level API knows is that you can't access it because it's already being accessed.  It likely would be difficult for it to provide a contextualized error message, and risky since it would have to retrieve additional information which itself could fail and cause a different even more misleading exception(generally you try to do as little as possible when handling/wrapping an exception).

So the bottom line is, for the error message to be more informative would make the error handling more fragile.

Perhaps a better wording would be "another thread or process" but I've found alot of Microsoft errors that are even more ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah; I think it's just a legacy thing that no one's found important enough to change for clarification.